# Openlayers change WMS call URL

Tags: openlayers, wms

I'm relatively inexperienced with Openlayers, and I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. Basically I've created a layer on my map from a WMS Call. I have the url set up so that when you click a radio button, it runs a function, and inserts the part of the URL that will link it to the proper file on the server. It's better to explain with code...

```
var layer_type = "Tavg_SDdiff";
var layer_name = "Tavg_SD_diff";


function layer_names(id) {

    layer_type = OpenLayers.Util.getElement(id).id;
    }


Tavg = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Tavg",
    "http://convection.meas.ncsu.edu:8080/thredds/wms/sco/synthesis/eval_WICCI_" + layer_type + "_50km.nc?",
    {layers: layer_name,
    version:'1.1.1',
    CRS:'CRS:84',
    "transparent":'true',
    "styles":'boxfill/shrmc-mxhgt',
    "colorscalerange":'-2.1,2.1',
    "numcolorbands":'42',
    "abovemaxcolor":'extend',
    "belowmincolor":'extend',
    time:"2001-01-01T00:00:00"},
    {isBaseLayer:false, setVisibility: true, transparent:true,displayInLayerSwitcher:true});
Tavg.url = "http://convection.meas.ncsu.edu:8080/thredds/wms/sco/synthesis/eval_WICCI_" + layer_type + "_50km.nc?";
```

So layer_type and layer_name change depending on what radio button is selected.
I know the variables change, becasue I have checked that with an alert() in my function.

Also I have a function that redraws the layer so the new data can be displayed.

```
function deleteLayer() {
    Tavg.redraw();
    alert(Tavg.url);
    }
```

Here is the problem, when I insert the alert in the second function, I see the URL does not change in the map variable, therefore it's not changing anything on the map when I select different buttons and the redraw command does its thing. Is it even possible to update the map without having to add a separate map variable for layers for each file?

Answer (score 1):

To change part of the WMS query string in OpenLayers, there is a mergeNewParams function, which will update it and re-request all of your tiles, see line 222, http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS.js. To be clear, this only works on the query string of the request.

In your case, it seems you have different layers and layer types as part of the url. You are going to have to call map.removeLayer(Tavg), create your new WMS request url and explicitly re-add the WMS with map.addLayer(Tavg) again.

In general, if you have some resource at some scale, which your url suggests you do, 
...thredds/wms/sco/synthesis/eval_WICCI_" + layer_type + "_50km.nc?", but with different thematic views, you might be better off handling this using the Layers and Styles parameters of WMS, with just one url, as otherwise you might end up with hundreds of different urls just to show different views of the same tile, which could get quite messy from a server perspective. Also, you will note from the fact that OpenLayers has a mergeNewParams function, that this is the expected way to handle this sort of situation.

**EDIT:** After a further dig through the source code, you might be able to do what you want by explicitly setting the url, with the setURL function following by a call to redraw. Both of these functions are in OpenLayers.Layer.HTTPRequest from which OpenLayers.Layer.WMS inherits some of its methods via OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.

```
wms.setUrl(newURL);
wms.redraw();
```

I have no easy means of testing this, so let me know if you have issues.